# How to set android:includeFontPadding for the Text component in React Native

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to set the [android:includeFontPadding](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:includeFontPadding) property on the the Text component in React Native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Native components have a style property `includeFontPadding` for this.

Comment: RN have includeFontPadding but seems like it doesn't work.